# Constraint validation not show message in form

Tags: symfony, constraints, message

I have a form that contains a user entity with an `$email` property:

```
{{ form_start(form, {'attr': {'class':'form-horizontal'} }) }}
{{ form_errors(form) }}
...
    <div class="control-group formSep">
        <label class="control-label">
            {{ form_label(form.email, 'E-mail:') }}
        </label>
        <div class="controls text_line">
             {{ form_widget(form.email) }} 
        </div>
    </div>
...
{{ form_rest(form) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

The user entity has constraints on `$email`:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64)
 * @Assert\Email
 * @Assert\NotBlank
 */
 protected $email;
```

When I put an invalid e-mail value the entity does not persist in the database (good), but twig doesn't display the error either (bad).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like said in the documentation form_errors(form) render global errors (like class constraint errors, etc...), to display the error for the email field you should use form_errors(form.email).

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html#form-errors-view